# Passing S3 Bucket Name with as a Parameter from properties file to aws-s3 camel component

Tags: java, apache, maven, apache-camel

I have a camel route end point as below where I want to replace the hardcoded s3 bucket name and replace with a parameter and pass it from a Properties file.

```
<to uri="aws-s3://input-test-bucket?amazonS3Client=#aws-s3-client"/>
```

I have a bean as below which passes the aws-s3-client containing the access key and the secret key

```
<bean id="aws-s3-client" class="com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Clie nt"> 
<constructor-arg> 
<bean class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials "> 
<constructor-arg index="0" value="${aws.accessKey}"/> 
<constructor-arg index="1" value="${aws.secretKey}"/> 
</bean> 
</constructor-arg> 
</bean>
```

The values for the aws.accessKey and the aws.secretKey are coming from a properties file from where I want the bucket name also to be taken.

Please could anyone let me know how to add the bucket name to the bean and pass it to the aws-s3 route as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can create a [S3Endpoint](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.1/html/API_Reference/files/camel/org/apache/camel/component/aws/s3/S3Endpoint.html) yourself and setup the [S3Configuration](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.1/html/API_Reference/files/camel/org/apache/camel/component/aws/s3/S3Configuration.html) as you want in spring. In that way, you can just setup the BucketName to the [S3Configuration](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.1/html/API_Reference/files/camel/org/apache/camel/component/aws/s3/S3Configuration.html) directly.

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <!--from uri="aws-s3://mycamelbucket?amazonS3Client=#amazonS3Client&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=5"/-->
        <from ref="s3Endpoint"/>
        <to uri="mock:result"/>
    </route>

</camelContext>

<bean id="amazonS3Client" class="org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.AmazonS3ClientMock"/>

<bean id="amazonS3Configuration" class="org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Configuration">
   <property name="amazonS3Client" ref="amazonS3Client" />
   <property name="bucketName" value="mycamelbucket" />
</bean>

<bean id="s3Component" class="org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Component">
   <constructor-arg index="0" ref="camel"/>
</bean>

<bean id="s3Endpoint" class="org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Endpoint">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="aws-s3://Unknowbucket"/>
   <constructor-arg index="1" ref="s3Component"/>
   <constructor-arg index="2" ref="amazonS3Configuration"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I am new to this..Please could you eloborate whether I need to create another bean with S3Configuration...

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this as well, but have you tried Property Placeholders?
http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Essentially, if you have a property named 'S3Bucket', for example:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <propertyPlaceholder id="properties"
                         location="classpath:org/apache/camel/component/properties/myprop.properties"
                         xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"/>

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
        <to uri="properties:aws-s3:{{S3Bucket}}?amazonS3Client=#aws-s3-client"/> 
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

This should work if:

- you have 'myprop.properties' in your classpath (in the appropriate path)
- that properties file contains a key 'S3Bucket' which maps to a value.

I'm not in a position to try and run this build but give it a shot!

Comment: Yeah, with the help of camel property place holder you can pass the property setting to any camel endpoint uri.